# embedding .dylibs and unix executable in a Flutter desktop app for Mac OS

Tags: flutter, macos, flutter-dependencies, desktop-application

I'd like to build a Mac OS application that embeds a "unix executable file" and it's .dylibs, but i don't know how to sign them so that the mac allows the user to execute the flutter app.

[image]

The unix file and it's .dylibs are a part of the Hugin application : a solution would be to force the user to install Hugin before, and use it's path ( /Applications/Hugin/PTBatcherGUI.app/Contents/MacOS/enfuse ) but it is not as seamless for the enduser.

I've seen this documentation : https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/macos/c-interop#compiled-dynamic-library-macos but it did not understood very well how to allow the embed of the unix file, and how to sign it.

Does someone knows where i could find a lead ?

Comment: You did not post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Build the `.app` properly, then codesign your bundle.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html